# how to create a regex that doesn't contain a text but starts with a specified text?

Tags: regex

Hi I'd like to create a regex that check if my string starts with a `/` but no matter where shouldn't contains `/!` so:

`/xxxx` = true

`/xxxx/yyyy` = true

`/!xxxx` = false

`/xxxx/!yyyy` = false

`xxxx` = false

I tried this but it doesn't seems to work:

```
^\/(?!(\/!)(.*|\/!.*))*$
```

Comment: The negative lookahead should be at the start `^(?!.*/!)/.*` as `/!xxxx` is also false. Use `.*` to  find it in the whole line https://regex101.com/r/3YSpOp/1

Answer (score 1):

As `/!xxxx` should also be false, the lookahead should be at the start of the string or else you will miss checking the leading `/`.

To find `/!` anywhere in the string, you could prepend  `.*`

```
^(?!.*/!)/.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3YSpOp/1)